# Как начать SVG анимацию с самого начала

Tags: html, svg, svg-animation

Вот простой пример SVG анимации.

Суть которого состоит в том, что есть две фигуры: круг и квадрат.

При клике по ***кругу*** он начинает смещаться вправо. ***Квадрат начинает*** двигаться вправо через одну секунду после начала анимации круга. В итоге в конце анимации обе фигуры находятся справа.

При повторном клике по кругу, ***круг*** снова оказывается слева и начинает двигаться вправо. ***Квадрат*** же остаётся на месте в котором закончилась его анимация (справа). И только через одну секунду он попадает в левую часть и начинает двигаться вправо.

Как сделать так, что бы при повторном клике по кругу обе фигуры оказались слева, ну а потом начали двигаться вправо? 
То есть, как запустить анимацию с самого начала?

HTML

```css
svg {
  border: 3px solid #eee;
  display: block;
  margin: 1em auto;
}

p {
  color: #aaa;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2em 0;
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="350">
  <circle id="orange-circle" r="30" cx="50" cy="50" fill="orange" />
  <rect id="blue-rectangle" width="50" height="50" x="25" y="200" fill="#0099cc"></rect>
  
  <animate 
           xlink:href="#orange-circle"
           attributeName="cx"
           from="50"
           to="450" 
           dur="5s"
           begin="click"
           fill="freeze" 
           id="circAnim"/>
  
  <animate 
           xlink:href="#blue-rectangle"
           attributeName="x" 
           from="50"
           to="425" 
           dur="5s"
           begin="circAnim.begin + 1s"
           fill="freeze" 
           id="rectAnim"/>
  
</svg>
<p>Кликните по кругу, чтобы анимировать его, а следом за ним и прямоугольник.</p>
```

[Ссылка на Сodepen](https://codepen.io/SelenIT/pen/mHpDG)

Comment: подпишусь под вопрос так как реально интересно что вы посчитаете решением

Answer (score 4):

Вопрос:

> Как сделать так, что бы при повторном клике по кругу обе фигуры
>   оказались слева, ну а потом начали двигаться вправо? То есть, как
>   запустить анимацию с самого начала?

Удалите `fill="freeze"` заморозку в конце анимации и оба элемента будут тут же возвращаться на место.
Добавил команду  `restart="whenNotActive"/>`,которая защищает от повторного запуска, пока анимация не дошла до конца.

```css
svg {
  border: 3px solid #eee;
  display: block;
  margin: 1em auto;
}
p {
  color: #aaa;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2em 0;
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="350">
  <circle id="orange-circle" r="30" cx="50" cy="50" fill="orange" />
  <rect id="blue-rectangle" width="50" height="50" x="25" y="200" fill="#0099cc"></rect>
  
  <animate 
           xlink:href="#orange-circle"
           attributeName="cx"
           from="50"
           to="450" 
           dur="5s"
           begin="click"
           id="circAnim"
           restart="whenNotActive"/>
  
  <animate 
           xlink:href="#blue-rectangle"
           attributeName="x" 
           from="50"
           to="425" 
           dur="4s"
           begin="circAnim.begin + 1s"
           id="rectAnim"
           restart="whenNotActive"/>
  
</svg>
<p>Кликните по кругу, чтобы анимировать его, а следом за ним и прямоугольник.</p>
```

Comment: Я хочу добиться несколько иного поведения. После окончания анимации обе фигуры должны остаться там где они закончили анимацию (справа). А вот при повторном клике по кругу, обе фигуры должны появиться слева и начать всё сначала.